# send arraybuffer from angularjs to c# endpoint

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have an ArrayBuffer in angularjs that I am trying to send to my backend endpoint in c#, I thought it was a regular byte array but it's not mapping appropriately

What would an ArrayBuffer map to as an object in c# if not a byte[]?.

I have a PDF file represented as that ArrayBuffer but now I would like to send it to the server, or perhaps is there a way to convert that ArrayBuffer to a File type in JavaScript and send it o the endpoint so that I can use something like an IFormFile?.

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome on SO :) If you want people to help you here, please don't hesitate to provide more context so they can [understand your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) more easily. For instance, try to provide [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of cases where your problem occur, and examples of desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a situation of same some long days back. What I did was, I converted the array buffer data to base 64 string in the js side and sent it to the backend c# code using post method,and again I decoded it to array buffer to regenerate the file on server side. By this way I achieved the mapping.

I used [this](https://gist.github.com/gyzerok/9210cea43c22395102a02d2b5e3f6b74) code which helps to convert the array buffer to base 64 string in JS.
and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2) api of .net framework to convert back the base 64 string to file buffer.

I hope this would help you.